# Sequelize migration changing column to be FK and then undo failing

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create migration file to changeColumn to be string (from enum) and to reference other table.

```
const enumStatus = ['PENDING', 'SUCCESSFUL', 'FAILED', 'FAILED_LAST_VALUE_MISSING', 'FAILED_LAST_DATE_MISSING', 'FAILED_OLD_LAST_DATE'];

module.exports = {
  up: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return Promise.all([
      queryInterface.changeColumn('MeasurementTestResults', 'status', {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }), queryInterface.addConstraint('MeasurementTestResults', {
        fields: ['status'],
        type: 'foreign key',
        name: 'statusFk',
        references: {
          table: 'MeasurementTestResultStatusEnums',
          field: 'code'
        },
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        onUpdate: 'cascade'
      })
    ]);
  },

  down: async(queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return Promise.all([
      queryInterface.removeConstraint('MeasurementTestResults', 'statusFk'),
      queryInterface.changeColumn('MeasurementTestResults', 'status', {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM(...enumStatus),
        allowNull: false
      })
    ]);
  }
};
```

db:migrate run flawlesly, but when i try to call db:migrate:undo it will execute commands out of order?

```
== 20201217194748-measurementTestResult_changeColumn_status: reverting =======
Executing (default): SELECT CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AS constraintCatalog, CONSTRAINT_NAME AS constraintName, CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AS constraintSchema, CONSTRAINT_TYPE AS constraintType, TABLE_NAME AS tableName, TABLE_SCHEMA AS tableSchema from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRA
INTS WHERE table_name='MeasurementTestResults' AND constraint_name = 'statusFk' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'iot_crcm_application_data1';
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `MeasurementTestResults` CHANGE `status` `status` ENUM('PENDING', 'SUCCESSFUL', 'FAILED', 'FAILED_LAST_VALUE_MISSING', 'FAILED_LAST_DATE_MISSING', 'FAILED_OLD_LAST_DATE') NOT NULL;
Executing (default): ALTER TABLE `MeasurementTestResults`
      DROP FOREIGN KEY `statusFk`;

ERROR: (conn=143438, no: 1832, SQLState: HY000) Cannot change column 'status': used in a foreign key constraint 'statusFk'
sql: ALTER TABLE `MeasurementTestResults` CHANGE `status` `status` ENUM('PENDING', 'SUCCESSFUL', 'FAILED', 'FAILED_LAST_VALUE_MISSING', 'FAILED_LAST_DATE_MISSING', 'FAILED_OLD_LAST_DATE') NOT NULL; - parameters:[]
```

then when i try to remove `queryInterface.removeConstraint('MeasurementTestResults', 'statusFk'),` this line from down script, it works, but no before i try it with error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to execute structure changes that depends on each other in parallel using `Promise.all`. You better call them one by one:

```js
await queryInterface.removeConstraint('MeasurementTestResults', 'statusFk')
await queryInterface.changeColumn('MeasurementTestResults', 'status', {
   type: Sequelize.ENUM(...enumStatus),
   allowNull: false
})
```

The same goes for `up` method too.

Comment: So simple, yet effective thanks a lot for. It's pretty new for me, and this is my first up down script.

Comment: Don't forget to add a transaction if MariaDB supports it for structure changes.